# Converting a Video from 1600*1200 to 1920*1080

Tags: software-recommendation, conversion, aspect, scale

How can I convert a video from 1600*1200 to 1920*1080 ?
I know that the aspect will be not correct, but I just like to do.

With Handbrake I can't do it, because it will not allow me to go beyond the 1600 pixels in the width.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you ok with using a command-line tool?

Comment: Yes , would be happy to know. I guess you gave me already helped me with the ffmpeg tool to make a video faster. Can I do it with ffmpeg ? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ffmpeg,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=1920:1080:flags=lanczos,setsar=1" output.mp4
```

This will stretch the video to 1920x1080.

---

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=-1:1080:flags=lanczos,setsar=1,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" output.mp4
```

This will keep the aspect ratio but place black bars on the left and right.

---

The `flag` in the scale filter determines the scaling algorithm to use. `lanczos` is the best available, in general, for video.

The `setsar` sets the pixel aspect ratio. Advisable to keep this square (`1`) unless you know what you're doing.

In the 2nd command, the `-1` tells ffmpeg to preserve original proportion when scaling height to `1080`. The pad fills out the canvas to `1920x1080` and centers the scaled video within it.

Comment: Can we add `blur background` of playing video or something like that instead `black bars`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43577377/